# In House of Stairs, what was Peter's secret?

Tags: house-of-stairs, william-sleator

In William Sleator's *House of Stairs* we find this passage at the end of the book:

> Peter and Lola were watching each other. Lola knew that their secret, the secret that they were about to give in when the elevator had come, was safe. And Peter knew that his own secret was safer still.

What was Peter's secret? It's not elaborated on in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter's secret is that hunger did not force him to give up; he pretended that it did because Lola would feel worse about being unable to hold out if she knew that Peter had been able to:

> But as Lola stared back at him, he knew that he would have to go
>   with her. Even though something in her had just broken, he understood
>   that she still hated the machine at least as much as he did, and would
>   always continue to. If he did not give in, and let himself die, she
>   would know for the rest of her life that success had been possible,
>   and that she had let herself fail. Whatever was going to happen to her
>   in the future, it would be far worse for her if she had to bear the
>   failure alone. And he realized that even more important than the fight
>   against the machine was his caring for her. He could not desert her.

Peter may have other secrets, but this is clearly the one that the OP's quote is referring to.

Answer (score 5):

One strong possibility is that it's Peter's closeted homosexuality. While these days, it's pretty much a non-issue, in 1974, when the book was released, it would be something that would be hidden to avoid being censured by society, possibly even more so in the dystopic world that they live in. Evidence for his sexuality are his tales of his prior close relationship with Jaxon in the orphanage, his crush on Oliver, and that he's the only male who doesn't have narrated sexual thoughts about the girls. Add to that he's described as being physically weak, especially in comparison to Oliver, which fits in with the stereotype.

Comment: I've requested a copy of the book from my library, because I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer, but it's the best one I have so far.

Comment: I thought he was molested. The "trances" Peter goes into are remniscient of molestation victims.

Comment: Ah, that could match also. Amd that would also be valid as a secret he wishes to hide.